# ffmpeg: convert jpg + mp3 into mp4 - Quicktime issue

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime

I have a.jpg (650 * 800 = 260KB)

I have a.mp3 (5:35 = 8MB)

And I used this script:

```
$ ffmpeg -loop 1 -i a.jpg -i a.mp3 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest a.mp4
```

And I got a.mp4 (at least **720P** very clear 5:35 = **16.3MB**)

Ubuntu movie player can play it, chrome / Firefox can play it, but Mac QuickTime can not open it.

So I upload to youtube, it becomes **480P** and when I download it back to PC it is not as good quality as my original, and it becomes **29.1MB** However it can be played by QuickTime.

So I did a second script:

```
$ ffmpeg -loop 1 -i a.jpg -i a.mp3 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest b.mp4
```

Now I get b.mp4 (same quality as a.mp4, but much larger at **40MB**), QuickTime can play it, but no sound. It plays normal at chrome / firefox.

What do I still not make right in above script?

Comment: Basic soln for the audio is `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i a.jpg -i a.mp3 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest b.mp4`. For the issue of size, will need to see full log of both your commands.

Comment: Thanks Mulvya works. however resolution degrades to same as youtube 480p and file becomes 12MB.